# Can I realize displaying action potential of a plant in a very minimal setup?

Tags: biopotential

I would like to show an experiment for kids on the Science day this April in our institute. It is inspired from this Backyard Brain's [experiment](https://backyardbrains.com/experiments/Plants_Mimosas). This experiment shows the action potential captured from the plant when the leaves shrink and displays the waves on a CRO. In my locality [shy plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosa_pudica) is available. But I don't have enough money to buy Spiker box kit from Backyard Brains. So I thought about another idea to realize the same.

Can I use TI's [INA111](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina111.pdf) chip to amplify action potential from shy plant? I am intending to do this on a breadboard. Basically I am thinking to connect a wire from the plant stem (and of-course properly grounded) and connect it to the input pin of the chip and then visualize the amplified signal.

---

**EDIT 1:** Specification of IC chip INA111 below from its datasheet :

[image]

---

**EDIT 2:** The Backyard Brain's spikerbox experiment in short is as follows. The spikerbox is a bioamplifier (instrumentation amplifier), which picks very tiny signals. So they connected the input wire of the spikerbox kit to the stem of plant and ground the other wire in earth properly. Also conductive gel is applied on the stem wire interface. Then the plant leaves are disturbed, which makes the leaves to shrink, which causes the action potential to pass through wire to spikerbox. From the output pin they connect the signal to CRO and you can observe the wave for the response of shrinking leaves.

---

**MY QUESTION**   :  So my specific question is as follows. I have resources like breadboard, DC power supply, few basic components like resistors, IC chips like AD623 or INA111, laptop with linux and free oscilloscope software etc. ***Can I realize displaying action potential in a very minimal setup ?***

Comment: Huh? What? ----

Comment: @OlinLathrop : why ? Is it too ambitious or foolish?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do (no, I'm not going to watch a video, you need to distill the information into a paragraph or so here), but you are a long way from a design detail like picking a particular amplifier chip.  So no real specs, and you didn't even provide a link to your proposed chip so we don't know what it is and what it can't do.  Again, no, not going to do your job for you and chase down specs.  This question is also too broad because it is really about a whole design.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : I will explain better.

Comment: It sounds like you want to buld your own version of this: https://backyardbrains.com/products/files/PlantSpikerShield.v.0.1.pdf But you should be clearer. Do you have an Arduino? Do you just need to make a cheaper or simpler version of whatever the "amplifier" in this schematic does?

Comment: @jdv : Yes I just wanted to make an amplifier.

Comment: @dexterdev, my recommendation is to ask abut what you want to do, and what stuff you have, and what you've done, instead of querying about a specific part. The former gives everyone context, and the latter becomes an exercise in trying to figure out what you actually want to do.

Comment: @jdv : I will edit the question, but I don't know if people will look into this "negative" question any more.

Comment: @dexterdev, I'm encouraging you to come back. Your project isn't over, and you received some useful information. Chances are, you'll need some further assistance, and this SE site is good at that. But there is an art to asking good questions.

Comment: @jdv : Is the question looking good now?

Comment: @dexterdev looks like enough details to get started.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that yes, you can probably use the TI instrumentation amplifier, but it's not as simple as you may think. It will be a project. You can find the [schematic for the SpikerBox](https://backyardbrains.com/products/files/SpikerBox.v.1.3c.Annotated.Schematics.pdf) on the Backyard Brains web site, and it does use an instrumentation amplifier, an AD623. But there's a lot more to it than that. How comfortable are you with building analog electronic circuits?

At the end of the day the SpikerBox is just an amplifier. It takes a faint biological signal and makes it audible. If your objective is to display the signals from the plant on an oscilloscope, you may not need an amplifier, because your oscilloscope already comes with one. Have you tried just hooking just hooking the oscilloscope probes up to the plant directly? If the signal is in the range of a several mV you should be able to see something.

Comment: The thing is that I have left less time with me and less resources. This is an idea which popped up for me. I will see if oscilloscope will pick it up.

Comment: This answer is good advice because it suggests the cheapest sort of development: just start experimenting with what you got. It may turn out that you need a unity gain fed into a 22x gain, bandpass filter and then into a configurable 1-5x final stage, but you should determine if you can just scope this out. If the signals are in the microvolt range, I suspect *some* sort of amplifier will be required.

Comment: @jdv : Is the unity gain feed a buffer circuit which gives current amplification. And why do I need a band pass filter?

Comment: An instrumentation amp will make things MUCH easier than using a scope, because of the differential input, interface potentials,  and high CMRR

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can absolutely use your instrumentation amp to do this.  I'd recommend an instrumentation amp with a gain of about 10, followed by a high pass filter with about a .5Hz cutoff, and then a plain old noninverting op amp with a gain of about 10.